# Not leaving blank pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, book

I want to force Adobe Indesign cs5 to begin any chapter of a book file on any page, odd or even, how can I do this? In other words, not leaving any blank page.
Thank you,
Ed

Comment: Not certain what you mean. InDesign doesn't just randomly throw in blank pages.

Comment: Doesn't your text automatically fall on the next page? InDesign will not put in a blank page by itself; you have to insert one.

Comment: Let me be more explicit. What I tried to mean is related to the beginning of a chapter after the preceding one. You can set Indesign to display the beginning of chapters on odd or even pages. For example, If you select on a odd page, and one chapter ended on a odd page, ID leaves the next page, even, blank in order to start the next chapter on the next odd page. What I really want is to starting any chapter on any page, odd or even, so that no blank page is left between two consecutive chapters. How can I accomplish that using ID?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you added those page breaks in the first place.

1. **Manually** with "Insert Odd Page Break" and/or "Insert Even Page Break": add a regular "Page Break" (without 'odd' or 'even') immediately after the current page break, then delete the previous break. (Do it in this order so you cannot accidentally paste the previous and next paragraphs together, which *will* mess up your paragraph styles.)
   See the Online Help: [Add column, frame, and page breaks](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/editing-text.html#add_column_frame_and_page_breaks).
2. With a **paragraph style**: change the style's Keep Options, "Start Paragraph" from "On Next Odd Page" or "On Next Even Page" to plain "On Next Page".
   See the Online Help: [Control paragraph breaks using Keep Options](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/formatting-paragraphs.html#control_paragraph_breaks_using_keep_options)
3. Manually through **Keep Options**: go manually through each of your chapters and adjust the Keep Options of the first paragraph.
   While you are doing that, ponder upon the positive points of using styles. For that, see the Online Help: [Paragraph and character styles](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/paragraph-character-styles.html).
4. With multiple documents in a **Book**: in the flyout menu of the Book Panel, go to "Book Page Numbering Options". Instead of "Continue on next odd page" or "Continue on next even page", choose "Continue from previous document". Make sure the checkbox to update existing page numbering is checked. If you previously added blank pages this way, you need to remove them manually after changing this setting -- InDesign does not automatically "remember" it added them earlier on.
   See the Online Help: [Number pages, chapters, and paragraphs in a book](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/creating-book-files.html#number_pages_chapters_and_paragraphs_in_a_book) , subsection "Start numbering on an odd or even page".